# Can't pass data to function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to successfully pass the result to another function and it's simply returning an undefined value:

```
function tagCustomer(email, tags) {
   var o = new Object();
   o.tags = tags;
   o.email = email;
   o.current_tags = getCustomerTags(email);
   o.new_tags = tags;
   console.log(o);
   return true;
}

function returnData( data ) {
    return data;
}

function getCustomerTags(email) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "xxx.io/index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {email: email, "action": "getCustomerTags"},
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
      returnData( data );
         return data;
      }     
   });
}
```

`o.current_tags` should get the result of `getCustomerTags`.

Comment: If you add `async: false,` to your AJAX options then this would work exactly how you think it should. Otherwise you need to get into promises and callbacks and stuff

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this (It's not good for UI, but with your current code it will work, also, look at the "**BETTER PRACTICE**" on the bottom of my answer):

```
function getCustomerTags(email) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: "xxx.io/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: {
            email: email,
            "action": "getCustomerTags"
        },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            result = data;
        }

    });
    return result;
}
```

The reason your code didn't work, is that the $.ajax success function is returning the `data` var, but `getCustomerTags` isn't returning anything. Also, pay attention to the "async: false", because if you use it as async, the function will return null because it will return before the ajax completes.

**BETTER PRACTICE**

The ajax function has a callback (success), USE IT!
design your code not as a method waiting for the ajax request result, **but as an ajax request that does something upon it's completion!**

**EXAMPLE**

```
function tagCustomer(email, tags, data) {
   var o = new Object();
   o.tags = tags;
   o.email = email;
   o.current_tags = data
   o.new_tags = tags;
   console.log(o);
   return true;
}

function getCustomerTags(email, tags) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "xxx.io/index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {email: email, "action": "getCustomerTags"},
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
          tagCustomer(email, tags, data);
      }     
   });
}
```

If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: `async:false` is bad because it locks up the browser, and I've never seen a good reason to use it.

Comment: I know, this is why I've added the "better practice" section on bottom of my answer.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is this the correct way to do this though or should there be another function to pass the data w/o having to use async -- Update: Sorry I didn't see above, how would I apply a more correct way to my code?

Comment: @user3399125 look at my updated answer. The good way is to call the ajax and then invoce whatever function upon its completion

Comment: @user3399125, you can look at the code on the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `getCustomerTags` to something like this since it makes an asynchronous request:

```
function getCustomerTags(email) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "xxx.io/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            email: email,
            action: "getCustomerTags"
        },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    });
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
getCustomerTags(email).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

You normal approach will not work here, because you try return before response comes back from server. Instead you use callback function or promises.

Comment: success() is deprecated, you should use `.done()`

Comment: @A.Wolff Good point, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You are dependent on ajax response to return data from the function. But ajax by default is asynchronous and does not wait for the server response. therefore your function does not return anything.